# How to get records of the same customer with two or more records in SharePoint using PowerShell and CAML query?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, caml

Get records from SharePoint using PowerShell

I have been trying to get records from SharePoint using PowerShell. With below query, I'm getting records where "customer_number" is not null. Instead, I want to get records where same customer having two or more records and not required to get records where customer having single records.

```
$Query.Query = "@
<Where>
    <And>
        <And>
            <And>
                <And>
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Lookup' >Unassigned</Value></Eq>
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='channel' /><Value Type='Text' >CCOM</Value></Eq>
                </And>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='RemType' /><Value Type='Text' >Remuy</Value></Eq>
            </And>
            <And>
                <Geq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True'>2023-04-24T00:00:00Z</Value></Geq>
                <Leq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True'>2023-04-24T23:59:59Z</Value></Leq>
            </And>
        </And>
        <IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='customer_number' /></IsNotNull>
    </And>
</Where>
"


$ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query) 
Write-host "Total Number of Items: "$ListItems.count

$dt = $ListItems.GetDataTable()
$go = $dt | Group-Object "customer_number"
$ad = $go | Sort-Object -Property {$_.Values[1]},{$_.Count} -Descending

$ad | Select-Object -Property {$_.Values[0]},{$_.Count}  |  Export-CSV ".\ExportAlert.csv" -Delimiter '|' -NoType
```

Comment: Please help me on this as I need to implement above logic immediately